# Error importing @philippdormann/elternportal-api module in TypeScript - "Cannot find module '@gymh/elternportal-api'"

Tags: typescript, vercel

I am attempting to use the @philippdormann/elternportal-api package from GitHub in a TypeScript file for my project. I have followed the installation instructions by running `pnpm i @philippdormann/elternportal-api`.

However, upon importing the API in my TypeScript file as mentioned in the documentation:

`import { getElternportalClient } from "@philippdormann/elternportal-api";`

I am encountering the following error:

`Cannot find module '@gymh/elternportal-api' or its corresponding type declarations.`

**Steps Taken:**

1. Installed pnpm on my Mac.
2. Installed the
   @philippdormann/elternportal-api.
3. Imported the API in my TypeScript
   file using the provided import statement.

**Additional Information:**

[The GitHub project URL](https://github.com/philippdormann/elternportal-api)

And that's how my folder structure in my project currently looks like:

[image: Folder structure]

I have now managed to import the package locally on my computer by creating a new project with `pnpm init`, installing the package with `pnpm i @philippdormann/elternportal-api`, creating the dist folder in a separate folder and replacing it with the old folder. I noticed that this package has its own node_modules folder. Should this be the case? Now that everything is working locally, I wanted to upload the API to Vercel, but I noticed that the dist folder is only created when I run `pnpm install` and then `pnpm build` in the separate `@philippdormann/elternportal-api` folder - independent of my project. When running `pnpm build` to create the dist folder in the `@philippdormann/elternportal-api` folder in my own project, I get the following error:

```
Error building /Users/Me/Desktop/elternportal-api/node_modules/.pnpm/@philippdormann+elternportal-api@2.1.0/node_modules/@philippdormann/elternportal-api: SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:5) in /Users/Me/Desktop/elternportal-api/node_modules/.pnpm/@philippdormann+elternportal-api@2.1.0/node_modules/@philippdormann/elternportal-api/src/index.ts
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (6:5) in /Users/Me/Desktop/elternportal-api/node_modules/.pnpm/@philippdormann+elternportal-api@2.1.0/node_modules/@philippdormann/elternportal-api/src/index.ts
    at pp$4.raise (file:///Users/Me/Desktop/elternportal-api/node_modules/.pnpm/@philippdormann+elternportal-api@2.1.0/node_modules/@philippdormann/elternportal-api/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@3.29.4/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:21621:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking in the [project package.json](https://github.com/philippdormann/elternportal-api/blob/master/package.json) file you can see that the package itself references `dist`:

```
"main": "./dist/index.cjs",
"module": "./dist/index.mjs",
"types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
```

You need to cd to the `@philippdormann/elternportal-api` folder and `build` to generate the `dist` folder to get types + compiled files.

Comment: I have successfully created the dist folder. What are the further steps to access the api in my typescript file?

Comment: @MultiMedia that should be enough. pnpm links to the folder containing `package.json` which then links to `dist`. Are you still experiencing the same problem? does running `build` produce the file `dist/index.cjs`?

Comment: Yes, the index.cjs file is created in the dist folder.
I tried to import the API in a new typescript file in the root directory of the GitHub project, as well as in a newly created folder where I copied dist into. Unfortunately both did not work. My goal is to develop an API that can then be deployed as a serverless function on netlify.

Comment: Hard to debug without knowing the folder structure. Assuming the following are side by side in root: @philippdormann/elternportal-api, your_project, .pnpm-workspace.yaml. pnpm links from `your_project` to `@philip...` and `@philip.../package.json` links to `@philip.../dist/...`

Comment: I only have the elternportal-api-master folder from GitHub in my root directory. Also, how does the .pnpm-workspace.yaml file have to look like?

Comment: you mentioned pnpm in your post, so I assumed you had set it all up: https://pnpm.io/workspaces

Comment: I added a screenshot of my current folder structure. I don't have a .pnpm-workspace.yaml file, but a pnpm-lock.yaml file. Do I also need the one you mentioned?

Comment: I assumed that your use of pnpm was for workspace linking, but that doesn't seem to be the case then. Sorry for the misunderstanding. If you just installed the package and want to use it, but get `Cannot find module '@gymh/elternportal-api' or its corresponding type declarations.` it's probably because the package doesn't include type declarations, ie it's built using typescript but it doesn't supply typings when used in typescript. If that's the case you need to use workspace linking or ignore types or write them yourself. I don't see your tsconfig file, but there might also be an issue there

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I am not very familiar with this area. What would be the best way to create a serverless function using this package?

Comment: I suggest linking the package via npm or pnpm so you get the typings or creating a .d.ts file and mocking the typings for the package

Comment: I have now managed to import and use the package inside of my project but encountered some other issues doing this. I edited my question to provide more information, due to the character limit of comments.